# How to get java path in CentOS?

Tags: java, path, centos7

I need to configure my Jenkins Server and I need to add Java path to Jenkins configuration.

**`yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk`**

However I'm new to lunix command, any suggestion please?

I dont know where yum install it!

> See the validated answer!

Comment: What do you mean by "java path".  Are you asking what the path to the `java` command is, or what `$JAVA_HOME` should be set to?  Or something else?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I mean both getting the path where java was installed, in order to set the $JAVA_HOME .

Comment: [vagrant@localhost /]$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/vagrant/.local/bin:/home/vagrant/bin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the solution

```
# cd /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/
# alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java 2
# alternatives --config java
# alternatives --install /usr/bin/jar jar /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/jar 2
# alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/javac 2
# alternatives --set jar /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/jar
# alternatives --set javac /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/javac 
# java -version

java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

# export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_79
# export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.7.0_79/bin
```

[Thanks to tecadmin](http://tecadmin.net/steps-to-install-java-on-centos-5-6-or-rhel-5-6/)

Answer (score 29):

try this if java command works

```
readlink -f $(which java)
```

Answer (score 23):

They usually reside in `/usr/lib/jvm`. You can list them via `ll /usr/lib/jvm`. The value you need to enter in the field `JAVA_HOME` in jenkins is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk`.

### Update

> when I look at '/usr/lib/jvm' I get ...

What you see there is a list of symbolic links pointing to a similar target located in `/etc/alternatives`. In the end they all point to the same target. The difference is only the name which allows you to choose how explicit your choice if the target version shall be.

(Because `java-1.8.0-openjdk` is missing: Maybe you also need to install the package `java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`.)

Comment: when I look at '/usr/lib/jvm' I get '[vagrant@localhost /]$ ll /usr/lib/jvm
insgesamt 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 16 13. Okt 11:30 java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.60-2.b27.el7_1.x86_64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 13. Okt 11:30 jre -> /etc/alternatives/jre
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 13. Okt 11:30 jre-1.8.0 -> /etc/alternatives/jre_1.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 13. Okt 11:30 jre-1.8.0-openjdk -> /etc/alternatives/jre_1.8.0_openjdk
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 50 13. Okt 11:30 jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.60-2.b27.el7_1.x86_64 -> java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.60-2.b27.el7_1.x86_64/jre

Comment: I added 'java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel' as you suggest, but I have the same result. Maybe the JDK is not installed, I see just JRE

Comment: I have `java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless`, `java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel` and `java-1.8.0-openjdk`

Comment: look at following or similar location /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/

Comment: In your root folder add this to .bash_src 
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

Answer (score -3):

Try echo $JAVA_HOME or look in vi ~/.bash_profile