# Spark-submit error line 71: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java: No such file or directory in Mac

Tags: java, macos, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to run the spark application on standalone mode, after installing the spark when i tried to run spark-submit command found the above error no java file found. Tried two different approaches.

- [approach-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834670/spark-class-line-71-no-such-file-or-directory) : able to remove the additional '/' by changing the environment file but still the issue persists
- [approach-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45012189/spark-class-java-no-such-file-or-derectory) : made the files having java home consistent but unable to find the spark.conf file where I could see to make it consistent.
- approach-3 : Tried to change the bash profile but no result either

Below is my bash_profile

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home

export SPARK_HOME=/Users/xxxx/server/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7

export SBT_HOME=/Users/xxxx/server/sbt

export SCALA_HOME=/Users/xxxx/server/scala-2.11.12

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$SBT_HOME/bin:$SBT_HOME/lib:$SCALA_HOME/bin:$SCALA_HOME/lib:$PATH

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin:$PATH

export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
```

Here is my etc/environment file:

```
JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

Could any help me in resolving this issue trying to run spark-scala application from 2 days on my **Mac**.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you [How to get java path in CentOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33104982/how-to-get-java-path-in-centos)

They usually reside in /usr/lib/jvm. You can list them via ll /usr/lib/jvm. The value you need to enter in the field JAVA_HOME in jenkins is /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_192

Here bin path should be present put the as Java Home path.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't see any `jvm` folder in /usr/lib/ , I'm not sure why but i can scala and java programs without any issues.

Comment: Just fyi i'm trying run this spark-scala application on my mac

Answer (score 0):

First, you can check that the Java environment variable was configured successfully, and then check that the java_home path in "sparkenv.conf" exists and that it is correct.
I hope I can help you.

Comment: I couldn't find the `sparkenv.conf` file in my mac instead i found `spark-env.sh` in `/Users/xxxx/server/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/conf` and i added java_home to it and yet i could see the same issue.

Comment: That's right, the "spark env.conf" file. You can view the path to your Java using the command "which Java" on the MAC terminal. Then "java -version" checks to see if the version of Java is compatible with saprk.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are running in Python, you can set Java environmental variable as follows:

Step 1. Find out where your Java/jdk is:

```sh
echo $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
```

(or `! echo $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)` in Jupyter notebook cell)

Step 2. Manually configure Java location:

```py
import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = <path-you-obtained>
```

This worked for me for using pyspark 2.4.x